# Node always returns empty array

Tags: javascript, node.js, angularjs

I have the following Get request in server...

```
var imageFiles = [];
var dir = 'public/img/';
fs.readdir(dir, function(err, files){
    if (err) return console.error(err);
    files.forEach(function(file) {
            file = dir + file;
            imageFiles.push(file)
    });
});
res.send(imageFiles);
res.end();
```

imageFiles always returns to `angular` as an `empty array`. If I `console.log(imageFiles)` before the response it is empty as well. However, if I `console.log(files)` they are all there. What am I doing wrong!?

Comment: You are sending the response before the directory was traversed. readdir is **asynchronous**. Send the response inside the callback.

Comment: If you're going to use NodeJS, you're really going to need to spend some time learning about async programming.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

fs.readdir is an async function.  It completes in the callback function passing files.

So, when you do res.send, images files is empty.

```
var imageFiles = [];
...
fs.readdir(dir, function(err, files){
    // files is populated here after readdir returns.
});

// this line executes before readdir returns
res.send(imageFiles);
```

You need to do something like:

```
var imageFiles = [];
...
fs.readdir(dir, function(err, files){
    ...
    res.send(imageFiles);
    res.end();
});
```

Welcome to async programming :)

Checkout async.js.  It helps untangle callback hell:

http://www.sebastianseilund.com/nodejs-async-in-practice

Comment: Thank you very much! I knew it was async and feel stupid for not thinking of that... I'll mark this as the answer as soon as I can.

Comment: np - takes some getting used to.

Answer (score 0):

Since `Array.prototype.forEach` is blocking, you can just call your other methods after the `foreEach` statement.
;

```
fs.readdir(dir, function(err, files){
    if (err) return console.error(err);
    files.forEach(function(file) {
            file = dir + file;
            imageFiles.push(file)
    });
    res.send(imageFiles);
    res.end();
});
```